# Create a specific object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I need to create an object array in javascript with this structure:

```
    var nodes = {
        '0': { 'label': 'abc' },
        '1': { 'label': 'cdf' },
        '2': { 'label': 'kjh' },
        '3': { 'label': 'wef' },
        '4': { 'label': 'vrg' }
    };
```

I have tried like this but with no success :(

```
    var nodes = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        nodes[i] = { i: { 'label': 'xpto'+i } };
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 var nodes = {};
 for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    nodes[i] = { 'label': 'xpto'+i };
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

this give the actual needed :

```
var nodes = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    nodes[i+""] = { 'label': 'xpto'+i };
}
```

Comment: The `+""` is useless.

Comment: the +"" turn the key as string instead of int

Comment: If you pass something which isn't a string, it's converted to a string first.

Comment: @Hacketo, really? just check it)

Answer (score 1):

just simple basic label code to create object array

```
var object = {};  // Object declaration 
var objectArray = [];  // Array declartion 

object = {'id':1 , 'propertyName1': "value1", 'propertyName2': "value2",'propertyName3': "value3"} // assign vlaue into object 

objectArray.push(object); // push object into array 

console.log(objectArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't to use variables in object keys..
So you always need provide it in your leftval:

```
nodes[i] = {'label': 'test'+i};
```